# How do I obtain the orientation of the Azure Kinect?

Tags: azurekinect

I believed the IMU would get me this information, but I was at first confused as to why it didn't. The IMU will only report live feedback of the device once it is in motion (like any phone would), but it doesn't give me information about its current state.

What I would like to have is a return of the camera's rotation (yaw, pitch, roll) at any given moment so that I could later calibrate my work to it. Is there a way to do this with IMU that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

IMU data begins streaming after calling k4a_device_start_imu(). If you are not seeing a stream then there is likely a bug in your code.

There is some documentation for k4a_device_get_imu_sample() here: https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/group___functions_ga8e5913b3bb94a453c7143bbd6e399a0e.html#ga8e5913b3bb94a453c7143bbd6e399a0e